# onClick eventlistener is not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs, function, event-handling

My code is not working properly and I can't understand why..

```
const MenuPage = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

    function handleClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        setTitle(e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].innerText);
        console.log(title);
    }

    return (
        <div id="menus">
            <div className="menus" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
                <div className="menu-box" id="menu" name="" >
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#099FFF" className="tt-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V9a.5.5 0 0 0 .252.434l3.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .496-.868L8 8.71V3.5z"/>
                </svg>
                <span className="menuTitle">Menu option 1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
};
```

At first I thought that onClick is not working but eventually I found that it is actually working and **state** is indeed changing but the 2nd statement `console.log(title)` in `handleClick` function is not loading on first click, I need to click twice then it loads `title` afterwards in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` is asynchronous.You can use `useEffect` to access the latest state after updating it.

```
useEffect(() => { console.log(title)}, [title])
```

The above `useEffect` will only be called when `title` is updated

Comment: got it.Thank you @zahra I have more power now with useEffect :)